# java create multiple excel files

Tags: java, excel, download, vaadin7

How to create multiple excel files and open for user to download. I am using next code for one, if I do it again , one after the other, I get two excels, but both are the one that is created second.

code to create first excel

```
GotrPersClass gotrPersClas = ...;
try {
    FileResource res;
    res = ReportTakeAway.generateCustomExcel1(gotrPersClas, office, dateF, dateT);
    if (res != null) {
        setResource("dlexcel", res);
        ResourceReference rr = ResourceReference.create(res, this, "dlexcel");
        getUI().getPage().open(rr.getURL(), "_blank", false);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

code to create second excel

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rs = ...;
try {
    FileResource resClass;
    resClass = ReportTakeAway.generateCustomExcel2(rs, office, dateF, dateT);

    if (resClass != null) {
        setResource("dlexcel", resClass);
        ResourceReference rr = ResourceReference.create(resClass, this, "dlexcel");
        getUI().getPage().open(rr.getURL(), "_blank", false);

    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

both codes are one after another

found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951455/loop-through-a-list-to-create-multiple-excel-files), but is not for java:

Comment: You need to show more code, especially the code that is producing the problem.

Comment: I added both codes. OK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the lines

```
setResource("dlexcel", resClass);
ResourceReference rr = ResourceReference.create(resClass, this, "dlexcel");
```

which create the reference for the client (browser) in both cases.
So regardless which download the user chooses, the file referenced as 'dlexel' will only provide one of the two.

https://vaadin.com/api/framework/7.7.30/com/vaadin/server/ResourceReference.html#ResourceReference-com.vaadin.server.Resource-com.vaadin.server.ClientConnector-java.lang.String-

Try to have unique values for the parameter 'key'.

Comment: yes, but also the line ``setResource("dlexcel", resClass);`` has to be changed . thanks

Comment: I edited my response so future readers will get it all in one step.